# How write stub method with NUnit in C#

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, stub

I have 2 classes:

- FirstDeep.cs
- SecondDeep.cs

  I did simple code for example:

```
class FirstDeep
    {
        public FirstDeep() { }

        public string AddA(string str)
        {
            SecondDeep sd = new SecondDeep();
            bool flag = sd.SomethingToDo(str);

            if (flag == true)
                str = string.Concat(str, "AAA");
            else
                str = string.Concat(str, "BBB");

            return str;
        }
    }
```

and

```
class SecondDeep
    {
        public bool SomethingToDo(string str)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            if (str.Length < 10)
            {
                //todo something in DB, and after that flag should be TRUE
            }
            return flag;
        }
    }
```

Then I want to write unit test for method "AddA":

```
class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void AddATest()
        {
            string expected = "ABCAAA";

            FirstDeep fd = new FirstDeep();
            string res = fd.AddA("ABC");

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, res);
        }
    }
```

And after that I have trouble, I don't know how correct write stub for method SomethingToDo in my Test class. I always have false. I should just return TRUE. But how?

Comment: you can still work with your pattern: introduce `bool expected = false; SecondDeep sd = new SecondDeep(); bool actualResult = sd.SomethingToDo("ABC"); Assert.AreEqual(excpected, actualResult);` ...!? if this doesn't meed your needs you sould probably consider to elaborate and improve your question!

Comment: Have you debugged your code? If it's happening in the database we can't help you as we have no details of what's happening there.

Comment: Yes, I debugged my code, and where I wrote: "//todo something in DB, and after that flag should be TRUE" I using class MembershipUser from .NET and this method can't connect to DB, that's why I should just return true on this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good way to allow you to write stubs is to use **dependency injection**. `FirstDeep` depends on `SecondDeep` and in your test you want to replace `SecondDeep` with a stub.

First change your existing code by extracting an interface for `SecondDeep` and then inject that into `FirstDeep` in the constructor:

```
interface ISecondDeep {

  Boolean SomethingToDo(String str);

}

class SecondDeep : ISecondDeep { ... }

class FirstDeep {

  readonly ISecondDeep secondDeep;

  public FirstDeep(ISecondDeep secondDeep) {
    this.secondDeep = secondDeep;
  }

  public String AddA(String str) {   
    var flag = this.secondDeep.SomethingToDo(str);
    ...
  }

}
```

Note that `FirstDeep` no longer creates a `SecondDeep` instance. Instead an instance is injected in the constructor.

In your test you can create a stub for `ISecondDeep` where `SomethingToDo` always returns true:

```
class SecondDeepStub : ISecondDeep {

  public Boolean SomethingToDo(String str) {
    return true;
  }

}
```

In the test you use the stub:

```
var firstDeep = new FirstDeep(new SecondDeepStub());
```

In production code you use the "real" `SecondDeep`:

```
var firstDeep = new FirstDeep(new SecondDeep());
```

Using a dependency injection container and a stubbing framework can make a lot of this easier to do.

If you don't want to rewrite your code you can use a framework for intercepting calls like [Microsoft Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/). In the next version of Visual Studio a similar technology will be available in the [Fakes Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

To make your code testable, do not instantiate dependencies inside your class. Use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (via constructor, property or parameter). Also use abstract classes or interfaces to allow mocking of dependencies:

```
class FirstDeep
{
    private ISecondDeep oa;

    public FirstDeep(ISecondDeep oa) 
    { 
        this.oa = oa;
    }

    public string AddA(string str)
    {
       return String.Concat(str, oa.SomethingToDo(str) ? "AAA" : "BBB");
    }
}
```

Depending on abstractions allows you to test your class in isolation.

```
interface ISecondDeep
{
   bool SomethingToDo(string str);
}

class SecondDeep : ISecondDeep
{
    public bool SomethingToDo(string str)
    {
       bool flag = false;
       if (str.Length < 10)
       {
           // without abstraction your test will require database
       }
       return flag;
    }
}
```

Here is test sample (using [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart)). It shows you how you can return `true` from call to your mocked dependency:

```
[TestFixture]
class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void AddAAATest()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock<ISecondDeep> secondDeep = new Mock<ISecondDeep>();
        secondDeep.Setup(x => x.SomethingToDo(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
        // Act
        FirstDeep fd = new FirstDeep(secondDeep.Object);
        // Assert
        Assert.That(fd.AddA("ABD"), Is.EqualTo("ABCAAA"));
     }
}
```